# SOAP or REST interface to JMS broker. "JMS over SOAP"

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, jms, activemq-artemis

My company long time ago decided to expose a JMS queue to customers in order to exchange data. We're in the process to migrate application server and we have to update all the client libraries. So we thought to expose a more "standard" interface.

We're looking to a simple way to expose a JMS queue through a standard SOAP or REST protocol. It's not SOAP over JMS, it would rather be the opposite "JMS over SOAP".

Seem that ActiveMQ(Artemis) has a REST protocol. It is a viable solution for us since we're migrating to Wildfly 10, but it's a bit complicated (see for instance posting a message requires 2 calls: see [Posting Messages](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/rest.html#posting-messages)), and it is ActiveMQ-specific. We have to implement it again for the old Weblogic servers.

The solution we're searching for should have the same reliability of JMS, in respect of the CAP theorem (providing message deduplication on send, and idempotent reads). Any suggestion?

Comment: can I ask why it has to be "JMS over SOAP" as it may seem to be simpler if it is the other way around, exposing your interfaces via web services and calling whatever beneath it.

Comment: SOAP over JMS uses JMS as a transport. So it has the same problems of JMS for interoperability. For instance (as far as I know) it is impossible for a client using .NET to connect to such a service.

Comment: JMS is not a transport. It's just an API. SOAP over JMS just uses underlying broker transport. Try not to confuse concepts of broker,transport protocol and messaging API.
And also Camel is just framework for integration services and will use underlying broker(ActiveMQ by default).
So basically you are looking for a broker with REST/SOAP API available. Why not to try ActiveMQ REST API? Also you can try to use STOMP protocol - it has wide spread and a lot of brokers support it.

Comment: And also you may look for exposing AMQP endpoint as an option. Most of languages have client libraries for that protocol.

Comment: @Dagon thanks for the clarification. I'll modify the question to take care of your notes. As i wrote in the question Artemis (the new name for ActiveMQ) has a REST protocol. We're considering it. The downside is that if we expose this to the customers we'll be tied to that technology, and we still have to support some old Weblogic 10 that doesn't have it... Plus it's not the most simple protocol i've ever seen. To send one message you have to call twice.

Comment: @Dagon see if the question is more clear now. Feel free to edit it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this is anti pattern where we want to combine both REST/Webservice and JMS or creating hybrid model.

JMS has strong reliability,performance,monitoring,exception handling, async response and guaranteed delivery in compared to REST/Webservice.
The only weaker point of JMS is external firewall access that can be overcomed by creating hybrid model.
Restful JMS.
http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html
http://activemq.apache.org/activesoap.html

Thanks